# Add activity family privacy

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Hello i am creating social site,in which i want one more option with family member,buddypress provide 'is_family' for family member,but at activity area how can we add one more option to the privacy of family .
See in screenshot below.I want to add one more option of family to the dropdown.

Activity privacy options
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @sonalip3 have you used this plugin [BuddyPress Activity Privacy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-activity-privacy/) ?

Comment: yes i used that plugin ,and i want same functionality with one more option ,that is 'family members'.In which only family member can access our activity.

Comment: Have you asked the author of that plugin if there are variants? There might be alternatives that other developers have forked that are ready to go.

Comment: yes i asked there and also asked in buddypress forum , but did not get any reply.

Comment: if you have solved the problem, please post it or even if not solved and have some more data, that will be helpful for people visiting this. may be I will answer it sometime .